# Read only children of a list that have a field with the value of auth.uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my DB structure

```
"tasks"
  "$taskId"
      ...
      "user": "firebase user id"
```

I have already written a rule `".read": data.child('user').val() === auth.uid"` under `$taskId`. When I try to access a single task, this rule is taking effect.

Will this also guarantee that if I write a query like `firebase.database().ref('/tasks').orderByChild('status').limitToFirst(1)` I'll only get tasks that have user id field as `auth.uid`. Or should I also write a `.read` clause under `tasks`

Answer (score 2):

There are several aspects to be answered in your question:

**1/ At which level should you write the security rules?**

If you write only at the `task` level like just follows, you will not be able to query the entire set of tasks.

You can test it by doing the following:

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
       "$taskID": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JS:

```
  var db = firebase.database();
  var ref = db.ref('tasks');

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("....", "....")
    .then(function(userCredential) {
      ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
           console.log(childSnapshot.val());
        });
     });
  });
```

This will fail with "Error: permission_denied at /tasks: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."

If you change `var ref = db.ref('tasks');` to var `ref = db.ref('tasks/123456');` (123456 being an existing task id) you will get a result.

If you change your rules to the following, the two previous queries will work.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

**2/ How should you do to only get tasks that have user id field as auth.uid?**

The first point to note is that "Rules are not Filters", as detailed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters

So if you implement security rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
        "$taskId": {
            ".read": "auth != null && data.child('user').val() === auth.uid",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to write a query that **includes the same restriction** on the user uid, like the following:

```
var db = firebase.database();

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("....", "....")
  .then(function(userCredential) {

      var ref = db.ref('tasks').orderByChild('user').equalTo(userCredential.user.uid);

      ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
         snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val());
         });
     });

});
```

But this query **will not work**, again, because "Error: permission_denied at /tasks: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."

You cannot do the following neither, since "Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths.":

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
        "$taskId": {
            ".read": "auth != null && data.child('user').val() === auth.uid",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

One solution is to use Query-based Rules (see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules)) and write your rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
        ".read": "auth != null &&
            query.orderByChild == 'user' &&
            query.equalTo == auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

---

However, as you have probably noticed, this will prevent you to order your query (and filter it) by something else than the `user` (e.g. by `status`), since "You can only use one order-by method at a time."

The solution would therefore be to create a second data structure in parallel to your existing structure, where you add the user as a top node, like

```
"tasks"
  "$taskId"
      ...
      "user": "firebase user id"
"tasksByUser"
  "$userId"
      "$taskId"
      ...
```

You would use the update() method to write to the two data structures simultaneously. See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Answer (score 0):

I gave `.read: true` under `tasks` and it is considering the rules written under the individual task objects before returning the results.